# Stop camel route if MQ becomes unavailable

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have one of the camel route as follows, there are many routes.

```
  from("jms:queue:TEST.LQ?transacted=true&connectionFactory=jmsConnectionFactory&cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE")
  .routeId("routeid")
  .autoStartup("true")
  .transacted("requried")
  ....
  ....
```

I getting below error if `TEST.LQ` MQ  or Queue manager is unavailable.

```
 ERROR [JmsConsumer[TEST.LQ]] [] [o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer      ] Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination
```

I tried to handle exception by catching below code, but `JmsMessageListenerContainer` only throws the message not an exceptiom

```
 onException(MQException.class, JMSException.class)
```

How stop route if IF MQ is not available?

Answer (score 1):

The camel jms component has the option for this -

Add the `testConnectionOnStartup=true` option in your `from(uri)` :

```
from("jms:queue:TEST.LQ?transacted=true&connectionFactory=jmsConnectionFactory&cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE&testConnectionOnStartup=true")
```

This will throw an exception if a connection is not available during startup which can then be handled.

More details are available in the [jms-component page](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html)

Comment: the above works only when camel start. but my requirement is to stop the route if MQ is not available in middle.

Comment: you could write a timer route, that does a health check on the JMS connection (enable them using spring-boot actuator). Once health check fails, stop the route and enable them when the connection is healthy

Answer (score 0):

@sree1611,

You can add exceptionListener or errorHandler query parameter in camel jms uri.
To create your own exception listener, implement org.apache.camel.spi.ExceptionHandler
To create your own error handler, implement org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler

I hope errors while consuming from MQ can't be bridged with camel error handlers, so you can't catch JMS exceptions (occurred during message consumption from MQ) in onException().